# this.collection.each does not fire this way (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using `this.collection.each()` to iterate through the collection fetched from the backend.

**Problem:** I notice that when I bind the `reset` event of the collection to the `render` method of the view in the `initialize` method and place a `console.log()` within `this.collection.each`, I see the console output as expected.

However, If I dont do the binding above, and simply use `this.render()` within `initialize`, the `console.log()` does not output anything. This seems really strange to me, can anyone provide an explaination?

I also placed a `console.log(this.collection);` just before the loop, and this always outputs the collection correctly! I was guessing that the collection has not been populated on initialization of the View, but that will cause `console.log(this.collection);` to not show anything.

**This Works**

```
SimilarPhotoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#modal_similar_items',

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.collection);
        this.collection.each(function(photo, index) {
            console.log('hello');
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

**This does not output from within this.collection.each()**

```
SimilarPhotoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#modal_similar_items',

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.collection);
        this.collection.each(function(photo, index) {
            console.log('hello');
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Both classes are instantiated via:

```
renderSimilarPosts: function() {
    this.similarPhotoList = new SimilarPhotoCollection();
    this.similarPhotoListView = new SimilarPhotoListView({ collection: this.similarPhotoList });
    this.similarPhotoList.fetch({
        data: {post_id: this.model.id},
        processData: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize your view, `this.similarPhotoList` is an empty collection. Therefore, when you create your `similarPhotoListView`, you're passing it an empty collection. `similarPhotoListView.initialize` calls `render` thus with an empty collection, all before the collection is populated by `fetch`.

The reason the first method works is because `reset` is triggered in `collection.fetch`. From the backbone source:

```
fetch:
...
    options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
            collection[options.add ? 'add' : 'reset'](collection.parse(resp, xhr), options);
            if (success) success(collection, resp);
          };
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`initialize` runs on instantiation, therefore you run `render` before you even pass in your collection. Additionally, `render` should not be called directly from `initialize`